# When is the 16.04 LTS .iso file available?

Tags: iso, 16.04, date

When is the 16.04 .iso file available? I mean the official .iso. I prefer torrent. Cant see any information on the page? Only 14.04 LTS :(

Comment: Today is the release day, check http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop later for it.

Answer (score 2):

When it is made available as a final release an announcement email will go out over the [mailing list](https://lists.ubuntu.com/archives/ubuntu-announce/), which you can subscribe to [here](https://lists.ubuntu.com/mailman/listinfo/ubuntu-announce).  There is no set time for 16.04 release though - it will be out when it is ready at some point on April 21.  Usually this is time zone agnostic so we don't base "April 21" on any one time zone.

Comment: I guess this mailing list is here: https://lists.ubuntu.com/archives/ubuntu-announce/ and you can subscribe here https://lists.ubuntu.com/mailman/listinfo/ubuntu-announce

Comment: @grooveplex Yep!

Answer (score 1):

From [insights.ubuntu.com](https://insights.ubuntu.com/2016/04/20/canonical-unveils-6th-lts-release-of-ubuntu-with-16-04/)

> LONDON 20th April 2016: Canonical announced today it will release Ubuntu 16.04 LTS on 21st April

Comment: Yes we got 21th April

Answer (score -1):

Download from here http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/daily-live/current/ 
Is avalible 20 Aprile.

Comment: Im watching for the official .iso not the daily :)

Comment: This is official, not marked as 'beta' in iso filename.

Comment: sure that its the final version?

Comment: zaebal, yes, this is final just download and install!

Comment: okay :) i will do

Comment: @ChrisZweiDreiMo  No it is not final - there's still a few things that need poked and finalized with approval first for a release.  Those images are not the final ones.